# Is Shakha-Bhed marriage prohibited? If yes then explain

Tags: rituals, practice, marriage

Is Shakha-Bhed (inter-Shakha) marriage prohibited? If yes, then explain why and where is it mentioned? Can a Rigvedi Brahmin marry a Yajurvedi Brahmin?

Comment: No, there are no restrictions on marriage between Brahmanas of two different Shakhas of the same Veda or Brahmanas of two different Vedas.  By the way, my Dad is the son of a Yajur Veda Brahmin and a Sama Veda Brahmin.

Comment: In general, a Brahmana man can marry a Brahmana, Kshatriya, Vaishya or even Shudra woman.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any such restriction.

Shakas (and most other Vedic traditions) are the son's responsibility to carry out, not daughters, because that is how lineage propagates.

If a Rigvedi brahmin man marries Yajurvedi brahmin woman, then the Rigveda tradition is continued by that couple. If it is Rigvedi woman and Yajurvedi man, then Yajurvedi tradition is continued.

Also, once a brahmin completes study of his birth-Veda, he can study the other Vedas.. so they are not prohibited from learning other Vedas, hence I don't see why they would be prohibited from marrying women born in families whose birth-veda is different.